# ESRI ArcGIS REST API URL giving me a blank image

Tags: rest, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to use the following URL to export a map image and I'm not getting anything other than a blank image...

http://demographics6.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Demographics_and_Boundaries_2016/MapServer/export?f=json&format=png&bbox=-82.728110%2C27.719379%2C-82.532320%2C27.816795&size=600,600&token=[my-token]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you constructing this url yourself or is that request coming from a layer added to the map?

After logging in to ArcGIS Online, I was able to use the export endpoint just fine with this url:

http://demographics6.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Demographics_and_Boundaries_2016/MapServer/export?bbox=-2.601910765504469E7%2C4619421.289780159%2C1199812.3691861853%2C1.6262309438175105E7&size=600%2C600&format=png&f=json

My hunch is you are supplying an invalid bounding box, it looks like it may be in a different spatial reference than the service, the service is expecting web mercator (102100) and looks like you may be giving it geographic (4326)

Comment: this was exactly the problem. and what i found was that you can specify the WGS84 (4326) in the URL so you don't need to convert/project it through some other service - http://demographics6.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Demographics_and_Boundaries_2016/MapServer/export?f=pjson&format=png&bbox=-82.596851999999998,27.820226999999999,-82.594852000000003,27.822227000000002&size=1400,1000&mapScale=75000&&dpi=96&bboxSR=4326&imageSR=4326